# Is there a way to ensure I'm told what item was sold?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

Sometimes when I sell an item on the Galactic Market I get a message saying "Someone has purchased the item you put up for sale"; other times, it mentions the specific item that was sold.  The former is useless if I'm trying to get a sense of how much I can get for particular items so I can maximize my profit.  Why does this happen?  Is there a way to ensure it tells me what items was sold?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

This is a bug that happens when they're reset the servers for maintenance/downtime. I doubt they consider it a high priority to fix.

So, if we were to enter a perfect world where there was no unscheduled maintenance, and you didn't have any items listed (or uncollected payments) when the server goes down, that should solve the issue for you.